# Android v7 Toolbar title text font

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I'm using Toolbar from android v7 support library. I need to set up custom font for toolbars title text using theme. Can someone please provide working example how to do that using Calligraphy (https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found that the current version of Calligraphy didn't work for me. I used the following method:

```
public static void applyFontForToolbarTitle(Activity context){
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) context.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    for(int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++){
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(view instanceof TextView){
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            Typeface titleFont = Typeface.
               createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/customFont");
            if(tv.getText().equals(context.getTitle())){
                tv.setTypeface(titleFont);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are already using Calligraphy lib, there is helper method `CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(..)` for manual font set up